# Should I call processEvents() on a thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, qthread, qtimer

`QThread` documentation suggests two ways to make code run in a separate thread. If I use `moveToThread` approach, I have to call `processEvents()` to issue the timeouts, to have the lambda executed. And this seems to cost a lot of CPU. Why is so?

```
class Worker : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    QTimer* timer;
    bool m_abort = false;
public:
    Worker() {}
    void abort() {m_abort = true;}

public slots:
    void run() {
        timer = new QTimer;
        connect(timer, &QTimer::timeout, []{qDebug() << "computed";});
        timer->start(1000);
        forever {
            if (m_abort) break;
            QCoreApplication::processEvents();
        }
    }
};

class MainWidget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
    QThread thread;
    Worker* worker;
public:
    MainWidget()
    {
        worker = new Worker;
        worker->moveToThread(&thread);
        connect(this, &MainWidget::start, worker, &Worker::run);
        thread.start();
        emit start();
    }
    ~MainWidget(){worker->abort(); thread.quit(); thread.wait();}
signals:
    void start();
};
```

However if I subclass QThread and reimplement run() it's not necessary to call processEvents. And CPU cost seems lower. Why?

```
class Worker : public QThread
{
public:
    Worker() {}

protected:
    void run() override {
        QTimer timer;
        connect(&timer, &QTimer::timeout, []{qDebug() << "computed";});
        timer.start(1000);
        exec();
    }
};

class MainWidget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Worker* worker;
public:
    MainWidget()
    {
        worker = new Worker;
        worker->start();
    }
};
```

Comment: IMHO it is almost always a bug to call `processEvents()`. There's usually always a better way. Same with having nested event loops (sometimes indirectly by using dialog boxes with `.exec()`). Those are all things that eventually lead to pain in Qt projects and should be avoided.

Comment: why do you need to use this `timer` and why you need `forever` loop for worker? You messed up something and I have no idea how to fix it since I do not see what exactly you are trying to achieve. Most probably you do not need threads at all. I'm suspecting [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/) so please provide more context. Please explain why do you think you need a multiple threads?

Comment: It superficially appears to me that your first solution is *"busy waiting."*  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_waiting ... **Not** what you want to do!

Comment: I suggest checking the QtWS19 [threading talk](https://resources.qt.io/qt-world-summit-2019/84-qt-based-threading-bo-thorsen-viking-software) by Bo Thorsen! Maybe you will find a better solution to your problem.

Comment: FYI, you should use at least `std::atomic_bool` instead of `bool` to manage your loop lifetime.

Comment: Worst thing that can happen by using just `bool` is that it might delay a little until the thread noitice it become `true`. Or is not that simple?

Comment: @KcFnMi no, anything can happen. Multiple threads accessing shared objects without synchronisation is undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

your run() function 'blocks' the thread. It is being invoked in the thread context, but never returns. This means, the event loop in the thread doesn't get executed anymore as soon as your run() funtion is called.

For the timer events to call your lambdas, the event loop has to be processed.
If you would modify your run function like this:

```
void run() {
    timer = new QTimer(this);
    connect(timer, &QTimer::timeout, []{qDebug() << "computed";});
    timer->start(1000);

    // don't loop here, instead exit the function 
    // and let the thread return back to the event loop
}
```

then your lambdas should get called. The thread will also keep running until you call `thread.quit()`

note: you can also connect directly to the '''started''' signal of the thread:

```
connect(&thread, &QThread::started, worker, &Worker::run);
thread.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

moveToThread approach might be improved by calling run() function just after thread emit started.

But I still don't know why the way I put it initially doesn't work.